# Watir Webdriver wait for page to load

Tags: webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

How to check whether a page is loaded or not using watir webdriver?

When i googled, I found many suggesting to check for a particular element which will be present only after the page is loaded. This doesn't help my requirement because the page load happens when I change the value of a list box and it doesn't take me to a new page. The elements and most of the values remain same after this page load. Therefore i need something like waitForPage in selenium RC.

My Scenario
1. There are three list boxes(A,B,C) in a page
2. When I change the value in List A, a page load happens (this will update the values for list box C. These values are dynamic.)
3. Then I have to change a value in List Box B.

In the above scenario if i have a List B element check after step 2, it says the element is present but while changing the value it fails saying the element doesn't exist

```
$browser.frame.select_list(:id,"listA").select("aaa")
while !$browser.frame.select_list(:id,"listA").exists? && i<=20
    sleep 1
     i+=1
end
raise "Element not found" if i > 20
i=1
while !$browser.frame.select_list(:id,"listA").include?("bbb") && i<=20
    sleep 1
    i+=1
end
raise "Option not found" if i > 20
$browser.frame.select_list(:id,"listB").select("bbb")
```

The script fails with element not found exception either while checking for presence of option in list B or while changing the value for list B

Comment: "2. When I change the value in List A, a page load happens" - what do you mean by this? Is there some kind of ajax request?

Comment: No smooyk. It is not an ajax request. The whole page is loaded again. It is a form submit using POST method

Comment: It sounds like updating List A refreshes the page to update the options of List C. Have you tried waiting until List C is updated? The code seems to only do inspections around List A.

Comment: Edit the text in the errors you raise so as to disambiguate the two messages so that it is clearer which step is failing

Answer (score 1):

If you are truely looking at a full page reload, and there is no AJAX going on (rare these days, where the trend is client side rendering) then the automatic waiting for page load that watir does after clicking links or submitting forms ought to work.  Using developer tools to watch net traffic will tell you if the page is actually doing a true reload, or it just looks visually like that is the case when client side js re-renders the page.

If you are faced with AJAX requests, where the submit is handled by a javascript request to some service, typically a REST Service, and a portion of the page updated, there are a few things you can do.

1. Decorate the code that calls on the element you are waiting for with the `.when_present` method.  For example:

   $browser.frame.select_list(:id,"listB").when_present.select("bbb")
2. If your client side code uses jQuery, you can construct a helper method that uses `Watir::Wait.until` to wait for `browser.execute_script('return jQuery.active == 0')` to be true and stay that way for some small period of time.  (.active is the count of active jQuery reqests waiting for a response)
3. Similar to other suggestions wait for a paticular page element to be present.
4. Combine the above, do #2 followed by one of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select all elements with id equals to "listB", iterate through them and check whether particular element is visible or not. I don't particular remember how it should looks like in watir, something likes this I think:

```
$browser.frame.select_lists(:id,"listB").each do |list|
    if list.visible?
        list.select("bbb")
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this didn't work out for me. The element exists before entering the page (looks like this code executes before page starts loading). After it enters the do block while checking the visibility or selecting, it throws element not found exception

Comment: It's hard to say without actual html code, but you can try the following, since page fully reloaded: after change of value of listA in your code, wait for element listB to disappear, then sleep for small amount of time(e.g. 1,2 secs.) and wait for listB to appears, I used such approach with single page app with a lot of ajax, and it worked out for me.